# Not sure how to relay requests to another router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, routes

I have the following files

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var api = require('./routes/api');
app.use('/api/v1/', api);
```

routes/api.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var users = require('./users');

router.get('/Users', users);

module.exports = router;
```

routes/users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        res.send('Hello world');
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should customise this by using separate routes file.

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    routes = require('./routes'); // Create a routes folder and under that create index.js

app.use('/', routes);
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    apis = require('apis');

router.get('YOUR API NAME', apis.api);
router.post('YOUR API NAME', apis.ANOTHER API HERE);
```

Create a folder apis and put your API under apis folder also create a index.js for exporting your APIs.

apis/index.js

```
var APIs = ['api', 'ADD MORE APIs here'];
APIs.forEach(function(api) {
   module.exports[api] = require(__dirname + '/' + api)[api];
});
```

hope this will help you : )

Comment: In this example my api.js would become index.js? Or would this be a step in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

In routes/users.js

Instead of

```
router.get('/')
.get(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello world');
});
```

Try

```
router.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello world');
});
```

Or

```
router.route('/')
.get(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello world');
});
```

Comment: I get 'Users' as output for some reason when I try this.

Comment: I'm using https://ide.c9.io/burtonium/node-from-scratch if you want to collaborate

Comment: You are sending 'Hi users' ?

Comment: https://node-from-scratch-burtonium.c9users.io/api/v1/Users should return 'Hi users'

Comment: what do you mean you get 'users' as output ? for which url ?

Answer (score 0):

Using router.use instead of router.get in api.js fixed it for me